# Ошибка в flask, помогите плиз

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

блок ошибок

```
ERROR:app:Exception on /posts [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Всё\Кирилла\Проекты-PYTHON\PyCharm\MySite\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "D:\Всё\Кирилла\Проекты-PYTHON\PyCharm\MySite\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1953, in full_dispatch_request
    return self.finalize_request(rv)
  File "D:\Всё\Кирилла\Проекты-PYTHON\PyCharm\MySite\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1968, in finalize_request
    response = self.make_response(rv)
  File "D:\Всё\Кирилла\Проекты-PYTHON\PyCharm\MySite\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2097, in make_response
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.
```

блок кода функции:

```
@app.route("/posts", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def posts():
    articles = Article.query.order_by(Article.date).all()
    render_template("posts.html", articles=articles)
```

блок кода html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}
Все статьи на сайте
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<div class="container mt-5">
<h1>Все статьи на сайте</h1>
<div class="container">
    {% for el in articles %}
    <div class="alert alert-info">
        <h2>{{ el.title }}</h2>
        <p>{{ el.intro }}</p>
        <p><b>Дата публикации: {{ el.date.date() }}</b></p>
        <button class="btn btn-warning">Детальнее</button>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

**Вопрос:**

> Как исправить эту ошибку?

Comment: Очевидно, вернуть что-нибудь из функции `posts`

Answer (score 0):

```
return render_template("posts.html", articles=articles)
```